# How do I parse the indentation level of a string into a JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, indentation

I'd like to be able to parse a string into a JSON Object, something like this (the text can be anything, I'm just putting them like this so you can see the structure):

```
A
  A-A
  A-B
    A-B-A
    A-B-B
  A-C
    A-C-A
B
```

into a json object, structured like this:

```json
[
  {
    "root": "A",
    "content": [
      { "root": "A-A", "content": [] },
      {
        "root": "A-B",
        "content": [
          { "root": "A-B-A", "content": [] },
          { "root": "A-B-B", "content": [] }
        ]
      },
      {
        "root": "A-C",
        "content": [
          { "root": "A-C-A", "content": [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { "root": "B", "content": [] }
]
```

So far, I have the following, but I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it. Maybe a recursive approach would be better?

```js
  let body = [];
  let indentStack = [0];
  for (let line of input.split('\n')) { // input is the string I'd like to parse
    if (line.trim() == '') continue; // skips over empty lines
    let indent = line.match(/^ +/);
    indent = indent ? indent[0].length : 0; // matches the first group of spaces with regex, gets the indent level of this line
    if (indentStack[indentStack.length-1] != indent) 
      if (indentStack.includes(indent)) indentStack.length = indentStack.indexOf(indent)+1; // remove all indent levels after it as it's returned back to a higher level
      else stack.push(indent);
    console.log(`${(indent + '[' + indentStack.join() + ']').padEnd(10, ' ')}: ${line}`); // debugging
      
    if (indentStack.length == 1) body.push({ root: line, content: [] });
    else {
      body[body.length-1].content.push({ root: line.substring(indent), content: [] })
    }
  }
  console.log(body)
```

Comment: If you don't mind using a library, a search on npm turned up this package: [indent-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/indent-tree).

Comment: @David784 Although that does look really good, I'm doing this for a personal project and would like to expand my knowledge on the subject. If this doesn't get much attention, I'll use it!

Comment: Understand completely. The source for that project is public on github, [here](https://github.com/hollowdoor/indent-tree/blob/master/src/index.js)...it's fairly short, and code looks quite readable. Might make a good resource...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do that this way :

```js
const data =
`A
  A-A
  A-B
    A-B-A
    A-B-B
  A-C
    A-C-A
B`;


function doTree(data)
  {
  let
    res    = []
  , levels = [ res ]
    ;
  for (let line of data.split('\n'))  
    {      
    let 
      level   = line.search(/\S/) >> 1  // (index of first non whitespace char) / 2 --> IF indentation is 2 spaces
    , root    = line.trim()
    , content = []
      ;
    if (!root) continue
    levels[level].push({root,content})
    levels[++level] = content
    }
  return res
  }

console.log( doTree(data) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

> The question about indentations ...

here you can have unequal indentation steps,
either with spaces or with tabs.
(do not mix spaces and tabs)

```js
const data_023c = // indentation values are 0c, 2c, 3c
`A
  A-A
  A-B
     A-B-A
     A-B-B
  A-C
     A-C-A
B`;

const indentation= (()=>  // IIFE 
  {
  let 
    indents = []
  , max     = -1
    ;
  return {
    clear:() => 
      {
      indents.length = 0
      max  = -1
      }
  , get:(line, lNum='?' ) =>
      {
      let ncBefore = line.search(/\S/)

      let level = indents.indexOf(ncBefore)
      if (level===-1)
        {
        if (ncBefore < max) throw `error on indentation,\n line = ${lNum},\n line value is = "${line}"`
        level = indents.push( ncBefore) -1
        max   = ncBefore
        }
      return level
      }
    }
  })()

const doTree = data =>
  {
  let
    res    = []
  , levels = [ res ]
  , lineN  = 0
    ;
  indentation.clear()
  for (let line of data.split('\n'))  
    {
    lineN++  // line counter for indent error message
    let
      root    = line.trim()
    , content = []
      ;
    if (!root) continue
    let level = indentation.get(line, lineN)
     
    levels[level].push({root,content})
    levels[++level] = content
    }
  return res
  }

console.log( doTree(data_023c) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: Well, it seems like it works! What does the rightshift do when defining level?

Comment: @Magnogen It is a mathematical trick, in computer science, all numbers are represented in binary. Dividing a binary number by 2 will always correspond to a shift to the right. It is the same thing when we calculate in base ten, a division by 10 operate also a right shift ex: 1230/10 = 123 ==> there is also a shift to the right. Your indentation value is on 2 caracteres, which means that all spaces counts have a pair value where their right digit on a zero. It's the same in base 10, all numbers multiple of 10 have a ends with a zero.

Comment: Ah, so this solution doesn't account for further indentation types, like 4 spaces and tabs? I wonder if I could modify it in some way to account for that.

Comment: @Magnogen I don't understand, you mean the indentation value is not constant? and the elements of the same level are not always aligned? and that the intention steps are not always the same throughout the document? Does that sound like a bad idea to me, or does it give off a syntactic error?

Comment: Yeah that would be a bit weird, but if someone were to use it with an indentation of 4 characters, or a tab, this wouldn't really allow for it. I have however come up with a solution for that as I've studied your code and will be answering this with what I found. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Magnogen My second version works on all sizes of indentations, and also for those with tabs. did you watch it too?